# Проверка наличия текста в переменной

Tags: java

Возникла такая проблема:
у меня есть переменная dx, в которую я ввожу букву и цифру (например D2).
Этим кодом я проверяю наличие буквы A,B,C,D,E и цифры 1,2,3,4,5 в переменной dx, и если есть недопустимая буква/цифра, то прошу ввести текст ещё раз, но этот код пропускает и другие буквы и цифры (например V7).
В чем моя ошибка?

```
package War;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Convert extends Main {
    public void convert(){
        for(;shipP==false&&shipP1==false;){
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            dx = scan.nextLine();
            if(dx.contains("A")||dx.contains("a")){
                x=0;
                shipP=true;
            }
            if(dx.contains("B")||dx.contains("b")){
                x=1;
                shipP=true;
            }
            if(dx.contains("C")||dx.contains("c")){
                x=2;
                shipP=true;
            }
            if(dx.contains("D")||dx.contains("d")){
                x=3;
                shipP=true;
            }
            if(dx.contains("E")||dx.contains("e")){
                x=4;
                shipP=true;
            }


            if(dx.contains("1")){
                y=0;
                shipP1=true;
            }
            if(dx.contains("2")){
                y=1;
                shipP1=true;
            }
            if(dx.contains("3")){
                y=2;
                shipP1=true;
            }
            if(dx.contains("4")){
                y=3;
                shipP1=true;
            }
            if(dx.contains("5")){
                y=4;
                shipP1=true;
            }
        }
        shipP=false;
        shipP1=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: А как понять "пропускает"?

Comment: Мне необходимо обязательное наличие буквы A-E и цифры 1-5 в тексте. Если есть недопустимая буква (G) или цифра (8), то должно просить повторный ввод текста

Comment: Попробуйте инициализировать `shipP=shipP1=false` перед `for`, а не после.

Comment: Добавил и в начале, и в конце. Не помогло

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, то нажмите на галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените ваш `for` на это

```
 while(!shipP || !shipP1)
```

или на это (привет  де Морган)

```
 while(!(shipP && shipP1))
```

И старайтесь не строить таких непонятных циклов

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Только вопрос: || означает "ИЛИ". Почему это работает? :D

Comment: Я обновил ответ. Наверное, второй вариант вам покажется более очевидным. Если да, то на ваш вопрос ответ найдёте в   [законах де Моргана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B5_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0)